# Bash command to match n line

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk, grep

I have an index HTML file with file/dir listing. It is just a usual filebrowser like :

```
...content here...    
<td><a href="20130011/">20120011/</a></td>
<td><a href="20130111/">20120111/</a></td>
<td><a href="20130211/">20120211/</a></td>
<td><a href="20130411/">20120411/</a></td>
...content here...
```

I don't understand how to extract the 2nd line from the bottom.

1) I downloaded HTML with curl

```
content=$(curl -sL "http://path-to-html")
```

2) then used

```
dir=$(echo $content | sed '/.*href="\([0-9]*\/\)".*/!d;s//\1/;q')
```

which gives me the last match : `20120411`.

But how to get the previous one ?

I don't know the total count of items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) program will print the penultimate line:

```
echo ${content} | awk '{ pen = ult; ult = $0 } END { print pen }'
```

This will print the penultimate *matching line*:

```
echo ${content} | awk '/href="([0-9]{8}\/)"/ { pen = ult; ult = $0 } END { print pen }'
```

If you just want to extract the first capture group:

```
echo ${content} | awk 'match($0, /href="([0-9]{8}\/)"/, a) { pen = ult; ult = a[1] } END { print pen }'
```

Putting it all together:

```
bash-4.2$ dir=$(curl -sL http://www.arteetmarte.no/tmp/index.html |
    awk 'match($0, /href="([0-9]{8}\/)"/, a) {
        pen = ult
        ult = a[1] 
    }
    END { 
        print pen 
    }
    ')
bash-4.2$ echo ${dir}
20130918/
```

Tested with: `GNU Awk 4.1.0, API: 1.0`

Comment: Can't understand how this can help in my case. I need regex and print pre-last match...

Comment: I've uploaded the tmp file, try it, not working `dir=$(curl -sL "http://www.arteetmarte.no/tmp/index.html" | awk -F'"' '{ pen = ult; ult = $2 } END { print pen }')`

Comment: @DmitriA: Since your data looks so different to the data in the question, I've updated my answer once more.

Comment: `GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Thank you! Just add ; after `pen = ult`

Comment: @DmitriA: The semicolon isn't required if there's a newline. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

May be a bit easier with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
dir=$(echo "$content"|awk '/href=/{x=p;p=$0}END{sub(/.*">/,"",x);sub(/<.*/, "",x); print x}')
```

Comment: Thanks, how to use it? Return an empty string for me.

Comment: Well, just tried like this with no luck: `content="<td><a href="20130011/">20120011/</a></td><td><a href="20130111/">20120111/</a></td><td><a href="20130211/">20120211/</a></td><td><a href="20130411/">20120411/</a></td>"
dir=$(echo "$content" | awk '/href=/{x=p;p=$0}END{sub(/.*">/,"",x);sub(/<.*/, "",x); print x}')`

Comment: @DmitriA, the `content` variable in your test does not contain embedded newlines (unlike the output from `curl`), so the command doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 0):

```
dir=$(echo $content | sed sed -n '/href="\([0-9]\{1,\}\/\)"/ {s|.*href="\([0-9]\{1,\}/\)".*|-\1-|;H;}
$ {x;l;s|.*-\([0-9]\{1,\}/\)-\(\n-[0-9]\{1,\}/-\)\{1\}$|\1|p;}')
```

The 1 in `\{1\}$` specify how much line must be removed from the end